# Removing session object creation from controller

Tags: php, symfony

I am developing a shopping cart in symfony2. I added products and I am storing in session. In order to show the cart (which is on top of every page), currently I am performing:

```
$session = new Session();
```

in every action of every controller.

What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: Create a base controller class which extends symfony's controller class and then inherit all your child controller with your base and do the common stuff in base controller also if you want to pass data to view for every action then in base controller override `renderView()` and pass your required data

Comment: hi @user1679267 i update my answer with a little improvement, hope this help. Consider to upvote my answer if you consider it useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In symfony2 framework the session is exposed as a service, so is better you don't manage the session lifecycle by yourself by let the container do it for you. You can also inject this in your custom service. So, as example, you can set an object in session like:

**A generic controller:**

```
 $user_id = $this->get('session')->set('user_id',null /*default value*/);

 $this->get('session')->set('product_id',$product_id);
```

See the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#managing-the-session) for further reference.

You can also access to the session service in the twig as follow:

```
{{app.session.get('product_id')}}
```

Hope this help.